# How to implement C++0x raw string literal?

Tags: programming-languages, string, language-design, c++11

How to define a working set of lexer and parser (*exempli gratia:* flex and bison) to support the C++0x styled raw string literals?

As you may already know, new string literals in C++0x can be expressed in a very flexible way.

`R"<delim>...<delim>";` - in this code the `<delim>` can be pretty much everything and also no escape characters are needed.

Any kind of parentheses can be used to delimit the end of string:

`R"(I love those who yearn for the impossible. (Von Goethe, "Faust"))";`

Blocks of text can be simply defined using equal occurrences of same characters:

```
R";***************************(
  ; TINY BASIC FOR INTEL 8080  
  ;       VERSION 2.0  
  ;     BY LI-CHEN WANG  
  ; MODIFIED AND TRANSLATED  
  ;    TO INTEL MNEMONICS  
  ;     BY ROGER RAUSKOLB  
  ;     10 OCTOBER, 1976  
  ;       @COPYLEFT  
  ;  ALL WRONGS RESERVED      )
  ;***************************";
```

*More information can be found [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C++0x#New_string_literals)(wikipedia) and [here](http://www2.research.att.com/~bs/C++0xFAQ.html#raw-strings)(att).*

I would like to use this fantastic feature in a language I am developing now.

So, how can I define a proper tokenizer and syntax analyzer to achive the result?

Thanks in advance for your answers!

Comment: I think your second example isn't a valid raw literal it should contain parentheses ( R"(;***...").

Comment: No, no... the sequence ;***... is a delimeter of a string; the raw string content begins after parentheses.

Comment: Here's the example from wikipedia: R"delimiter(The String Data \ Stuff " )delimiter".

Comment: I think by virtue of the fact that it requires a backreference, it's not strictly regular, and I'm not sure that flex will do that for you. A Perl pattern that would match something similar might be `/R"([^()]+)[(](.*?)[)]\1"/`. Any lexer maker that allows backreferences and reluctant quantifiers should be able to do something similar. Otherwise, you might need to write some sort of preprocessor. Good luck...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could proprocess literals in lexical analysis stage and transform them into something like meta token.

```
Input:  
    int a;  
    char *b = R"....";  

Preprocessed:  
    int a;
    char *b = R*literal[0]*;

Tokenized:  
    INT symbol[0] DELIM  
    CHAR OP_ASTR symbol[1] OP_EQ symbol[2] *literal[0]* DELIM  

Symbol table contents { "a", "b", "R" }  

Literal table contents { "...." }
```

*literal[0]* is the pointer to the original literal text.

Comment: You can process any non-regular, special syntax constructs in lexical analysis stage using custom subroutines.

Comment: This is kind of hybrid lexico-grammatical analysis; I think I understood the idea! Thank you!